# Kusto query remove double entries

Tags: distinct, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a query that returns several entries with timestamp and an operation_Id.
Entry 2 and 3 have the same operation_Id but different timestamps. How can I remove the duplicate operation_Id, the first shall be used - and I still want to display the timestamp.

| timestamp | operation_Id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-28T06:13:05.789Z | 12d83416-0c94-4c98-9523-603b7e634a14 | iOS |
| 2022-10-28T03:50:44.249Z | 642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b | iOS |
| 2022-10-28T03:50:42.662Z | 642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b | iOS |

I know I can use "distinct".

```
| distinct operation_Id, OS;
```

| operation_Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 12d83416-0c94-4c98-9523-603b7e634a14 | iOS |
| 642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b | iOS |
| 642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b | iOS |

But how do I add now the timestamp?

I cannot do something like this, because then I am back to my first problem :-)

```
| distinct timestamp, operation_Id, OS;
```

I also tried with "summarize" but it summarized all operation_Id, even the operation_Id was different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[arg_min()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-min-aggfunction)

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, operation_Id:string, name:string)
[
    datetime(2022-10-28T06:13:05.789Z) ,"12d83416-0c94-4c98-9523-603b7e634a14" ,"iOS"
   ,datetime(2022-10-28T03:50:44.249Z) ,"642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b" ,"iOS"
   ,datetime(2022-10-28T03:50:42.662Z) ,"642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b" ,"iOS"
]
| summarize arg_min(timestamp, *) by operation_Id
```

| operation_Id | timestamp | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 642bb5d7-69e5-437a-b086-d89eec93438b | 2022-10-28T03:50:42.662Z | iOS |
| 12d83416-0c94-4c98-9523-603b7e634a14 | 2022-10-28T06:13:05.789Z | iOS |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA53QTUvEMBAG4Huh/yH0tJVMycckTfIP9uRBT4osSROWgOkubTys%20OOtX4jgQZw5vTDzHN7o67bhMe1qLmmtvpxd9DW9JUpO57T4mk/zYR/dWpc8HymZfUmfoW%20b%207Yh23z97AQTAjgDYW6Zdlw6pobR2Lue0I6LaCRyDWyyCDhZA1YJCZrJMCYt0XPstrt8fdO9s/RXVjrFHOIg8IPVKEJQcQRtkwKUo4fAjIZobEqTlShN%20DMrBq3FP9iHtnkh61MpfsnPifjleCh5/m6VkquehMuPSl8BWxssPX0BAAA=)

Comment: oh... I already tried

| summarize arg_max() by operation_Id

but then I noticed, that one entry was missing. And I thought this was the wrong way.

However, with arg_min it works.

Thank you so much.

Comment: If "first shall be used" then you are looking for arg_min, not arg_max. Pease make sure to close the loop and accept the answer.